# How can I capture incomplete date/time values as they are entered in a `datetime-local` element?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, knockout.js

Knockout provides the `textInput` binding for updating observables immediately rather than when the element value changes (which only happens when the element blurs). Unfortunately, this doesn't work when the input type is `datetime-local` in Chromium.

I'm attempting to write a custom binding that mimics the `textInput` behavior; I need to be able to get the working value of the `datetime-local` element as the user is entering it.

Chromium's behavior for this kind of element is bizarre. The `input` event only occurs after a full date *and* time has been entered. What's more, if the input loses focus before the full date is entered, the value remains empty, as though nothing had been entered at all.

As an aside, initializing the element with a complete and valid value is not an option in my case, as I need to distinguish between date/time values that have actually been entered from blank values.

For reference, here is the code I'm working on:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.date = {
    init: (element, valueAccessor) => {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "input", () => {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            if (!!element.value) {
                value(new Date(element.value).toISOString());
            } else {
                value("");
            }
         });
    },
    update: (element, valueAccessor) => {
        var value: any = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var output: any = "";
        if (!!value) {
            output = value.toISOString();
        }
        element.value = output;
    }
};
```

Comment: KO also provides `value` binding. Using it with [type=text] inputs (with no `valueUpdate`) will update bound observables on _blur_ event.

Comment: The `value` binding doesn't work. I want to update observables _immediately_, not just after blur. I also want to use it for `[type=datetime-local]`.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue. Although it might not necessarily help in your situation, I've considered separating into `date` and `time` so at least you'll get `date` if they happen to enter that.

Comment: That's a good suggestion for a workaround. Unfortunately its too costly for me to implement in the particular project I'm working on.